# How do I format dates as yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.0000000Z in R?

Tags: r, datetime

How can I convert a date from Sys.Date() to the date format (yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.0000000Z) in R?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think OP is looking for 7 post comma positions. I think maximum is 6, but I am not sure! To get 6 we could use `Sys.time()
options(digits.secs = 6)  Sys.time()`.

Comment: Yes, I apologize... it was 6 positions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time output formats are given in `?strptime`. One way to get what you want it:

```
 format.Date(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m-%dT%R:%OS6Z")
 #[1] "2022-07-19T00:00:00.000000Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this using `strftime` with the format:

```r
strftime(Sys.time(), format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS6Z")
#> [1] "2022-07-19T17:58:09.005532Z"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>